# View controller won't return to previous view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

The scenario is when the app first loads (controller A loads), it checks if an NSDefaultuser exist. If it does not exist then it sends it to (Controller B). In controller B the user enters his/her username then clicks ok. Now, NSDefault is saving the username and it should also redirect it back to the main view controller. Here is the code:

```
if([Username.text  isEqual: @""]) {
    [self showOkAlert:@"Username required"];
}
else if([Password.text isEqual:@""]) {
    [self showOkAlert:@"Password required"];
}
else  {
    //suppose that login was successfully.
    [self SaveCredentials];


    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LatestNews"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Controller A:

```
- (void)LoadCredentials {
//load username
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *username = [defaults objectForKey:@"User"];

if(!username) {

    [self showAlert:@"user does not exist"];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}else{
    [self showAlert:@"user exists"]; 
    // for testing purposes I want it to reset when user logged in. Just so I know it resets. Later this method will be called from logout button.
    [self resetUsernameWhenLogout];       
}
}
-(void)resetUsernameWhenLogout {
//reset username when logout
NSDictionary *defaultsDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *key in [defaultsDictionary allKeys]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self LoadCredentials];
}
```

Comment: A thread error ? can you check the value of [NSThread isMainThread] first ? If it's false you are creating a thread somewhere and trying to use UIKit in not the main thread will not work or worse will partially work. (btw saving a password in user default is not good at all, you should use the keychain, maybe with a wrapper https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)

Comment: No matter what I try it does not let me go back. any ideas why?

Comment: I am not saving the password just username.

Comment: Thread 1: Breakpoint 3.1 this is what I get. It is not really an error it is just kicks out of the simulator back to xcode and it displays it on the screen.

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; This helped I am able to go back when placing it in the control B fixed above

Comment: Do you accidentally have a breakpoint set? Try going to the breakpoints tab (second tab from the right on the left sidebar), removing any that are there, and running again.

Comment: No breakpoints set. Now, I am able to return to main page. But when I click on anything is giving the same problem but this time is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: How does controller A "send it to controller B"? Can you show us that code?

Comment: I added controller A above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities here; Firstly, iOS8 seems to instantiate the VC's a lot earlier than in iOS7, so the Navigation tree isn't complete in viewDidLoad, You should only use viewDidLoad for additonal initialization. Try moving your code  [self LoadCredentials];
} to viewWillAppear.

Secondly, if you have a nav controller, you should be adding the new VC to the nav tree via the nav controller. If this is the case, try the code below.

```
  if([Username.text  isEqual: @""]) {
      [self showOkAlert:@"Username required"];
  }
  else if([Password.text isEqual:@""]) {
      [self showOkAlert:@"Password required"];
  }
  else  {
      //suppose that login was successfully.
      [self SaveCredentials];

     //This does not work - I receive a thread error not sure how to debug it 
      UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
      UIViewController *targetViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LatestNews"];
      UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
    if (navController) {
        [navController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
    }

  }
```

Comment: this does not load Controller A when clicking Login from controller B. It saves the credentials though.

Comment: So controller A is the main controller? and in Controller A you check if the user has logged in, if not, (in ViewWillAppear) you send to controller B? how are you dismissing controller B? Controller A will already be in the nav tree so you simply need to dismiss B and not create a new controller A... am i missing something?

Comment: Now, that i placed it in the controller B it works fine like you said.